# Client Side Validation for a views exposed filter in ajax mode

Tags: views, bootstrap-theme

I tried this using bootstrap theme
Create a view for a content type
Add an exposed filter using one of the fields of that particular content type
Make the filter field as required
Now on visiting the view page, the exposed filter rendered as a textbox with an outer red border, which normally should appear after hitting the submit button of the filter.
Someone help me explain this behavior.
Secondly edit the same view, click on the filter field and uncheck the required checkbox.
Then Under Advanced, Enable use Ajax to make the filter work in ajax mode.
Now if i try to write a client side validation for the filter textbox using jquery( say i check for an empty and return an error msg div or even return false, it is being ignored) and all the results are displayed.

Any suggestions are welcome. I'm not making any errors in my validation script if needed i can post the script too.

Comment: Please add your validation JS to the question, would be very useful

Answer (score 0):

```
     $('.catalog-submit').on('click', function() {
  var textVal = $(".catalog-search").val();
  if(textVal == "") {
    $(".catalog-search").css('border-color', 'red');
    $(".err-msg").remove();
    $(".catalog-submit").append("<p class='err-msg'>Please Enter your City and State, or Zip Code</p>");
    return false;
  }
});
```

The above code by default should append the err-msg div and return nothing.
However this code appends the err-msg and returns every single result. I mean the return false has no effect. A simple return also did the same. And this is the js I have used for my case.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens 
I have posted the script to ensure that the script i used is error free as suggested by Beebee